# display add on value in the console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, typescript

- I am new to js.
- i am trying to display add on value in the console.
- I am not sure how to access addOns.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code below.

https://jsfiddle.net/6f8upe80/

```or-tag-here
private sports: any = {
        networkNo: 241,
        startDate: "04/10/2018",
        endDate: "04/24/2018",
        addOns: [
            "sports"
        ]

    }
  //console.log("this--->" , this);
  console.log("this.sports.addOns--->" + this.sports.addOns);
```

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to find a way to access the value you can declare the variable in local scope and access it.

```
let sports: any = {
    networkNo: 241,
    startDate: "04/10/2018",
    endDate: "04/24/2018",
    addOns: [
        "sports"
    ]

}
console.log("this.sports.addOns--->" + sports.addOns);
```